# Adding a dictionary to NSMutableArray from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, swift

I have an Obj-c superclass, with

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sectionChanges;
```

And in Swift I am trying to add a dictionary to it:

```
self.sectionChanges.addObject([NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert: 1])
```

We get

```
'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'Key'
```

I have tried a lot of options:

```
self.sectionChanges.addObject([NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert: 1] as NSDictionary)
```

Changed the error to

```
Type 'NSFetchedResultsChangeType' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'
```

Then I try:

```
self.sectionChanges.addObject([Int(NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert): 1] as NSDictionary)
```

and get:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'NSDictionary'
```

Running out of options... Then same code in Obj-c is simple:

```
[self.sectionChanges addObject:@{@(type): @(sectionIndex)}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Swift imports as a Swift enumeration any C-style enumeration marked
>   with the NS_ENUM macro.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.”
>   iBooks. https://itun.es/tw/1u3-0.l

So `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` is a Swift enumeration now, and you can't pass it to Objetive-C.

You might want to try this:

```
self.sectionChanges.addObject([NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert.rawValue: 1])
```

Comment: Thank you! Oh for those helpful error messages, didn't even think that the problem was with the enum